# HTML, Is it possible to change validation message location from the "required" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have a tabbed modal with different languages. I want every **title** & **text** for my 2 languages to be required, but when I am focused on one tab, the validation messages from the other tab pop up to the top left corner of the screen for some reason.

(Sorry, when I try to take a sceenshot the validation message dissapears but I think you get what I am saying)

So my modal is the following: 
[image]

Now what I want to do is, when I am focused on the **English** tab and  click **Save** but the Greek language fields are empty, I want the validation message to appear on the **Greek** tab link, instead of the top left of the screen (which happens for whatever reason)

For example could I do something like the following with jQuery:

```
$('#myElement').attr("required").location = ???
```

Is this possible? If not, how do I go about this?

Any help, suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank for the suggestion. I added one line of code, the only thing I could think that could lead to an answer. Honestly there is not much to add here, it's more about whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

example: https://jsfiddle.net/wakirin/nfoqacyy/

```
$('#btn-save').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  var inputs = 0;
  $.each($('.tab-pane'), function(k,v){
    inputs = $(v).find('input:required').filter(function() {return !this.value.length;}).length + $(v).find('textarea:required').filter(function() {return !this.value.length;}).length;

        $('a[aria-controls="'+$(v).attr('id')+'"]').removeAttr('style');

    if (inputs > 0) {
        $('a[aria-controls="'+$(v).attr('id')+'"]').css({color: '#a94442'});
    }
  });
  if (inputs == 0) {
    alert('OK!');
  }
})
```